# Play! framework - GET variables

Tags: java, web, playframework-2.0

what is the most efficient/elegant way to extract variables from a GET request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is better way than reading a `queryString()` (it returns a `Map` which you have to process manually). Use `play.data.DynamicForm` instead:

```
public static Result aboutAMan() {
    DynamicForm df = form().bindFromRequest();

    int age;
    String name;
    boolean isAdmin;

    name = (df.get("name") != null) ? df.get("name") : "The Unknown";
    age = (df.get("age") != null) ? Integer.parseInt(df.get("age")) : 0;
    isAdmin = Boolean.parseBoolean(df.get("is_admin"));

    String about = (name + " is " + age + " years old and " + ((isAdmin) ? "is" : "isn't") + " an admin");

    return ok(about);
}
```

of course you can also use shorter version while getting single params

```
public static Result aboutAMan() {
    return ok("ellou' " + form().bindFromRequest().get("name"));
}
```

link is:

```
http://localhost:9000/about-a-man?name=SockSocket&age=23&is_admin=false
```

route is:

```
GET    /about-a-man     controllers.Application.aboutAMan
```

Answer (score 1):

found. just use request().queryString()